# PHP json_encode(): why does encoded non-associative array return an empty string?

Tags: php, json

I'm experiencing a problem when trying to `json_encode()` a non-associative array in PHP:

```
echo json_encode(array(array(1,1), array(1,1)), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT) ;
// Non-associative array output as object: {"0":{"0":1,"1":1},"1":{"0":1,"1":1}} 

echo json_encode(array(array(1,1), array(1,1))); 
// Non-associative array output as array: "" (empty string)
```

The PHP version used on my server is 5.3.

How do I get a non-associative array output as array `[[1,1],[1,1]]`?

Comment: I can get it to work using your second code. It outputs "[[1,1],[1,1]]"

Comment: Should work as intended http://3v4l.org/pknk5

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski You forgot the PHP tags. [However, this should work.](https://eval.in/193740)

Comment: @MCEmperor wrong link copied. I changed it to 3v4l.org anyway...

Comment: there's no way json_encode would convert a non-empty array to an empty string. I'm calling PEBKAC. Even an empty array would encode as `[]`, not `""`.

Comment: well in fact it doesn't show anything it's just empty output. Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you considered upgrading PHP? Many bugs have been fixed since, and that code definitely works with recent versions.

Comment: which PHP version are you guys testing this with?

Comment: actually my exact php version is 5.3.5 did anyone else experienced this problem? Can you also put a note of which version of PHP you are using when answering the question? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! problem solved after PHP version upgrade to 5.5

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved after PHP version upgraded to >=5.5